# How can I add element_text color scale as legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph that groups the x-values by comparison (to a value) and also color scales the `x.axis.text` by using a vector. Legend is created for geom only but I want to add another legend for `element_text` colors also.

I tried `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = a))` but it didn't work.

This is very similar to my code

```
#Create data
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
y <- c("10", "9","-10","11","-3","-15")
data <- data.frame(x, y)
data$y <- as.numeric(as.character(data$y))
data$category <- ifelse(as.numeric(data$y)<10, 0, 1)
data$category <- as.factor(data$category)
a <- ifelse(data$category == 0, "purple", "black")
#Graph
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = category)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = a))
```

Is there any way to add theme color scales as a legend?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = category)) +

  # invisible geom_text layer to trigger generation of legend for text colour
  geom_text(aes(label = y, color = category), alpha = 0) +

  # specify colour mapping accordingly with alpha = 1
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "purple", "1" = "black"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = a))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since it was a busy week, I just had time to try your solution. This is a great answer. Unfortunately, I realized the question is not clear enough. I need a second legend because there are two separate categories. Such as the axis text and bar colors are not necessarily the same category. I should update "data$category <- ifelse(as.numeric(data$y)<0, 0, 1)" criteria as less than 10 so it will be better representing my problem. Thank you :)